# Angular http interceptor response headers

Tags: angularjs, http, express, header, interceptor

I have made an http interceptor in which I need to evaluate responese headers and find particular one (authorization). Interceptor itself is working however it is unable to list headers which I am setting on server side and which I can clearly see set in firebug's network tab.

interceptor:

```
app.factory('HttpItc', function($q, $localStorage, $injector) {
return {
response: function (response) {
   //console.log(response); // Contains the data from the response.

  var freshJwt = response.headers['Authorization'];

  if (freshJwt) {
    $localStorage.jwt = freshJwt;
  }

  // Return the response or promise.
  return response;
}  };});
```

[image: headers in firebug:]

[image: evalueated response:]

This is how I set headers in Express on the server side:

```
return res
                    .header('Authorization', jwt)
                    .header('testHeader', 'testValue')
                    .json(user);
```

What is happening? How can I get access to response headers in http's interceptor?

Comment: Can you try this please and see if you get any results console.log(response.headers('Content-Length'));

Comment: @stackg91 it's 'null'. But the Data object in that response is properly set and populated...

Comment: I think you can get the authorization headers by calling `var jwt = response.headers('Authorization')`

Comment: @themyth92, you were right. it should be accessed as function...
also you need to have 'Authorization' header set as exposed on the backend side. thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to call `response.headers('...')` (as a function, not an array).

Also be sure to explicitly expose headers on the back-end side.

EDIT: 
To explicitly expose headers on the back-end you would need to add something like

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers","yourHeaderName");
```

This is similar to adding CORS headers, and currently does not work with '*'

Comment: I think it should be plural `response.headers('...')`

Comment: Not working '*' with expose-headers header made my day.

Comment: add "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: yourheader"  on server (php, java, nodejs) works smoothly